# How to define a dynamic table layout with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to create sort of gallery for images and videos. I decided to use flexbox properties for creating a table of divs will be containing media.

But the problem is that I need to create the table automatically without having to define how many rows and columns I will need.

For instance if I have 2 images, then it generates a table of 2 elements.
If I have 6 photos/videos then I have a table with 3 rows, where each has 2 columns, and so on.

I need something like this:

[image]

But instead I have this:

[image]

Does anyone knows is possible to create such table in flex without having to predefine rows and columns?

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rosybrown;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  background: red;
  margin: 1%;
  flex: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well with `flex: auto`, your items are _allowed_ to shrink in width, so that they all fit into one row, and don't wrap. You will need to define a width for what you want to achieve here. If you want to do that dynamically based on the number of items, then look into what has been dubbed "quantity queries" - https://alistapart.com/article/quantity-queries-for-css/, https://quantityqueries.com But assuming this will probably be generated dynamically on the server side, it might be a bit easier to simply count the items, and add a class to the container based on that.

Comment: Have you tried using css `grid` ? https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Comment: Have you thought about using bootstrap?

Comment: Have you tried to add `width` to `.item` style?

Comment: schmauch,  yes i  also tryed with width and height. But it didn't help

Comment: It's not exactly clear how the 'dynamic' part is expected to work. With 2 elements, you say a "table" is created. Is that one row & two columns, or two rows and one column? Likewise, your image shows 8 elements in two rows across four columns... but your description above says 6 elements should be in two rows across three columns... **How many columns do you want before a new row is started?** And **What if there are an odd number of elements?**

Comment: @Pogrindis Grid would not be useful because there are a dynamic number of rows and columns here. Grid layout requires knowing the layout ahead of time. OP could combine grid with flexbox somewhat, but grid alone is not useful here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for :

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rosybrown;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  width: 20%;
  background: red;
  margin: 1%;
  flex: auto;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
</div>
```

By limiting `item` class with width/height, you can do what you are looking for.

Comment: For width it would be best to use flex-basis, and if height is parent dependent you might run into some problems.

Comment: Yes, but here we don't know the context. That's why I talk about managing height. Maybe he wants fix to show a number, or maybe he wants to show text with unknow size

Answer (score 2):

Here you go! You were close with your CSS for the containing element, all you needed to add was:

```
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: auto;
  align-content: start
```

As far as for the flex-item,

flex-grow, flex-shrink, and flex-basis can be converted to the shorthand property:

```
flex: 0 0 auto;
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: auto;
  align-content: start
}
.item {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  margin: 6px;
  background-color: red;
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  font-size: 2rem;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to define at least an 'approximate' width for the children. It's best to test on each screen size, but basically it's the `flex-basis`.

To achieve the quantities you need in each screen size you'll probably need to put some media queries for that basis.

```css
html,
body{
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rosybrown;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  background: red;
  margin: 5px;
  flex: 1 1 200px; //#!#
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
</div>
```